# What is the 'M' attribute in windows file system for?

Tags: windows-10

I can't find a reference to the "M" attribute shown in the image.
File properties details

[image]

Comment: only guess would be Media, but you are correct it is not listed anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS` (0x400000). It is settable only by the OS (in this case by the OneDrive filter driver).

It slightly modifies the meaning of the 'O' (Offline) attribute, by indicating that the offline file will be automatically made available as soon as its data is accessed, without having to explicitly request this via FSCTL_RECALL_FILE.

(Windows has had the concept of "offline" files since ~2000, so the 'O' attribute used to mean that the file was moved to something like an automated tape-storage library, and had to be manually recalled before use.)

- Microsoft: [File Attribute Constants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants)

Comment: In the linked resource I cannot find anything that associates `M` with `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS`. How do you know this is it?

Comment: PowerShell's `Get-Item foo | fl Attributes` reports this attribute in numeric format on those files (and only those) which also show the "M" attribute in Explorer, and all other attributes can be ruled out (e.g. `ReparsePoint` corresponds to "L" for "Link"), so it is the only one that remains unaccounted. It's a recent attribute judging by its high value, and happens to be next to other attribute bits that were also added for OneDrive purposes (the undocumented 0x8000 "Pinned" and 0x100000 "Unpinned"). Also, it matches the order of the letters.

Comment: IMO this should be in the answer. For now the answer looks like a wild guess. Investigating in PowerShell is research.